# TypeError: collections.Map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My page appears with TypeError: collections. Map is not a function
This here is my JS code. I dont know what the problem is

```
    this.state = {
        collections: SHOP_DATA
    };
}

render() {
    const {collections} = this.state;
    return (

        <div className='shop-page'>

        { collections.Map(({id, ...otherCollectionProps}) => (
            <CollectionPreview key={id} {...otherCollectionProps} />
        ))}

    </div>
    );
}
```

}

export default ShopPage;

Comment: use `map` smallcaps

Comment: @Semi-Friends - "Lower case," not "smallcaps." Smallcaps is sᴏᴍᴇᴛʜɪɴɢ ᴇʟsᴇ. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using Map instead of map

```js
  this.state = {
        collections: SHOP_DATA
    };
}

render() {
    const {collections} = this.state;
    return (

        <div className='shop-page'>

        { collections.map(({id, ...otherCollectionProps}) => (
            <CollectionPreview key={id} {...otherCollectionProps} />
        ))}

    </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: hahaa thanks a lot smh